# Can I use a collection initializer for Dictionary<TKey, TValue> entries?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, collections, c#-3.0

I want to use a collection initializer for the next bit of code:

```
public Dictionary<int, string> GetNames()
{
    Dictionary<int, string> names = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    names.Add(1, "Adam");
    names.Add(2, "Bart");
    names.Add(3, "Charlie");
    return names;
}
```

So typically it should be something like:

```
return new Dictionary<int, string>
{ 
   1, "Adam",
   2, "Bart"
   ...
```

But what is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: Check this post: https://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/object-and-collection-initializers-in-csharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper way to initialize a C# dictionary with values already in it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047602/proper-way-to-initialize-a-c-sharp-dictionary-with-values-already-in-it)

Comment: don't think that's a dupe, because they were asking, not for the shorthand dictionary declaration syntax, but for why the shorthand wasn't working in their (ancient) setup.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

```
var names = new Dictionary<int, string> {
  { 1, "Adam" },
  { 2, "Bart" },
  { 3, "Charlie" }
};
```

Comment: When does the initializer work? Is it only for `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` subclasses or will also work on `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`?

Comment: after C# 3.0 you can use `var` instead of the declaring type, or if leaving the declaring type can omit the `new Dictio...` -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-c-sharp-array-initialization-syntaxes

Comment: @drzaus: Using var is an ugly, ugly practice though; C# is a strongly typed language.

Comment: @Nyerguds: what?  `var` literally just saves you keystrokes, it's [_implicitly_ strongly typed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx).

Comment: @drzaus And it creates a difference between writing immediately-initialized variables and variables initialized later. It's an ugly practice.

Comment: @Nyerguds -- you're entitled to your opinion, I guess, but if you're immediately initializing your variables there is literally no difference between using `var` and repeating yourself with `SomeType obj = new SomeType...`.  And since you can't declare `var obj;` without immediately initializing, I just don't see the problem.  Really, I'm trying to learn, but I can't grok your position.

Comment: Not that it matters, but if you're using intellisense using var usually involves 2 MORE keystrokes; the IDE should suggest the type for you if you've already defined it. In terms of bad practice the problems only come in when you expect a collection to be of a base type, but small changes in the code can cause the IDE to switch it to the extended version. It generally doesn't cause any problems because it only happens when you're not using any of the base implementations anymore anyway, but it can cause structural problems to be hidden without you realizing. I prefer explicit declarations too.

Comment: @Shimmy, I think it's just a shorthand for calling `Add` multiple times. I can't remember what the exact requirements are to get it working.

Answer (score 36):

The syntax is slightly different:

```
Dictionary<int, string> names = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    { 1, "Adam" },
    { 2, "Bart" }
}
```

Note that you're effectively adding tuples of values.

As a sidenote: collection initializers contain arguments which are basically arguments to whatever *Add()* function that comes in handy with respect to compile-time type of argument. That is, if I have a collection:

```
class FooCollection : IEnumerable
{
    public void Add(int i) ...

    public void Add(string s) ...

    public void Add(double d) ...
}
```

the following code is perfectly legal:

```
var foos = new FooCollection() { 1, 2, 3.14, "Hello, world!" };
```

Comment: Great answer, I didn't know about that! Anyway, when does the dictionary initializer work? Is it only for Dictionary<TKey, TValue> subclasses or will also work on ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>?

Comment: @Shimmy Collection initializers work on anything that implements `IEnumerable` _and_ has `Add()` methods.

Comment: @Shimmy: dictionaries are collections

Comment: @JohnSaunders But a dictionary initializer accepts two parameters for `Add`.

Comment: @Shimmy: why does that matter? The point is that it will work with _any_ class that implements `IEnumerable<T>` and which has an `Add` method. If the `Add` method takes _3_ parameters, then you'll need 3 objects in the brackets.

Answer (score 11):

```
return new Dictionary<int, string>
{ 
   { 1, "Adam" },
   { 2, "Bart" },
   ...
```

Answer (score 10):

The question is tagged `c#-3.0`, but for completeness I'll mention the new syntax available with C# 6 in case you are using Visual Studio 2015 (or Mono 4.0):

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
   [1] = "Adam",
   [2] = "Bart",
   [3] = "Charlie"
};
```

Note: the old syntax mentioned in other answers still works though, if you like that better. Again, for completeness, here is the old syntax:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
   { 1, "Adam" },
   { 2, "Bart" },
   { 3, "Charlie" }
};
```

One other kind of cool thing to note is that with either syntax you can leave the last comma if you like, which makes it easier to copy/paste additional lines. For example, the following compiles just fine:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
   [1] = "Adam",
   [2] = "Bart",
   [3] = "Charlie",
};
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for slightly less verbose syntax you can create a subclass of `Dictionary<string, object>` (or whatever your type is) like this :

```
public class DebugKeyValueDict : Dictionary<string, object>
{

}
```

Then just initialize like this

```
var debugValues = new DebugKeyValueDict
                  {
                       { "Billing Address", billingAddress }, 
                       { "CC Last 4", card.GetLast4Digits() },
                       { "Response.Success", updateResponse.Success }
                  });
```

Which is equivalent to

```
var debugValues = new Dictionary<string, object>
                  {
                       { "Billing Address", billingAddress }, 
                       { "CC Last 4", card.GetLast4Digits() },
                       { "Response.Success", updateResponse.Success }
                  });
```

The benefit being you get all the compile type stuff you might want such as being able to say

`is DebugKeyValueDict` instead of `is IDictionary<string, object>`

or changing the types of the key or value at a later date.
If you're doing something like this within a razor cshtml page it is a lot nicer to look at.

As well as being less verbose you can of course add extra methods to this class for whatever you might want.

Comment: This is basically how a ViewDataDictionary works in MVC - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607985/shorthand-for-creating-a-viewdatadictionary-with-both-a-model-and-viewdata-items

Comment: I experimented with types as 'aliases' for Dictionarys and typed arrays, presuming it would be safer, in a typed world, to use predefined types.. Turned out not to be so useful when it came to generics and linq.

Answer (score 1):

In the following code example, a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is initialized with instances of type `StudentName`.

```
  Dictionary<int, StudentName> students = new Dictionary<int, StudentName>()
  {
      { 111, new StudentName {FirstName="Sachin", LastName="Karnik", ID=211}},
      { 112, new StudentName {FirstName="Dina", LastName="Salimzianova", ID=317}},
      { 113, new StudentName {FirstName="Andy", LastName="Ruth", ID=198}}
  };
```

from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx)

Answer (score -3):

Yes we can use collection initializer in dictionary.If we have a dictionary like this-

```
Dictionary<int,string> dict = new Dictionary<int,string>();  
            dict.Add(1,"Mohan");  
            dict.Add(2, "Kishor");  
            dict.Add(3, "Pankaj");  
            dict.Add(4, "Jeetu");
```

We can initialize it as follow.

```
Dictionary<int,string> dict = new Dictionary<int,string>  
            {  

                {1,"Mohan" },  
                {2,"Kishor" },  
                {3,"Pankaj" },  
                {4,"Jeetu" }  

            };
```

Comment: There are already 6 other answers showing how to do this.  We don't need a 7th answer showing the same thing.