# How to insert values into C# Dictionary on instantiation?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Does anyone know if there is a way I can insert values into a C# Dictionary when I create it? I can, but don't want to, do 
`dict.Add(int, "string")` for each item if there is something more efficient like:

```
Dictionary<int, string>(){(0, "string"),(1,"string2"),(2,"string3")};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use a collection initializer for Dictionary<TKey, TValue> entries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495038/can-i-use-a-collection-initializer-for-dictionarytkey-tvalue-entries)

Answer (score 219, accepted):

There's whole page about how to do that here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx

Example:

> In the following code example, a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is
>   initialized with instances of type `StudentName`:

```
var students = new Dictionary<int, StudentName>()
{
    { 111, new StudentName {FirstName="Sachin", LastName="Karnik", ID=211}},
    { 112, new StudentName {FirstName="Dina", LastName="Salimzianova", ID=317}},
    { 113, new StudentName {FirstName="Andy", LastName="Ruth", ID=198}}
};
```

Comment: This only works on .NET 3.5 compiler though... just keep that in mind.

Comment: @kd7iwp - no problem, part of the function of this site is so that alternative search terms can get routed to something useful.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much a given with Microsoft.  They have been pretty committed to backward-compatibility over the years.

Answer (score 50):

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string> { 
   { 0, "string" }, 
   { 1, "string2" }, 
   { 2, "string3" } };
```

Answer (score 15):

You were almost there:

```cs
var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{ 
   {0, "string"}, 
   {1, "string2"},
   {2, "string3"}
};
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also use Lambda expressions to insert any Key Value pairs from any other IEnumerable object. Key and value can be any type you want.

```
Dictionary<int, string> newDictionary = 
                 SomeList.ToDictionary(k => k.ID, v => v.Name);
```

I find that much simpler since you use the IEnumerable objects everywhere in .NET

Hope that helps!!!

Tad.

Answer (score 9):

Just so you know as of C# 6 you can now initialize it as follows

```
var students = new Dictionary<int, StudentName>()
{
    [111] = new StudentName {FirstName="Sachin", LastName="Karnik", ID=211},
    [112] = new StudentName {FirstName="Dina", LastName="Salimzianova", ID=317},
    [113] = new StudentName {FirstName="Andy", LastName="Ruth", ID=198}
};
```

Much cleaner :)

Answer (score 7):

You can instantiate a dictionary and add items into it like this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>
    {
        {0, "string"},
        {1, "string2"},
        {2, "string3"}
    };
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope it will work perfectly.

`Dictionary<string, double> D =new Dictionary<string, double>();
 D.Add("String", 17.00);`

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! The person who originally asked this question specifically said that they don't want to do the `.Add(int, "string")` method of adding values to a dictionary. Sorry but this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

This isn't generally recommended but in times of uncertain crises you can use

```
Dictionary<string, object> jsonMock = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "object a", objA }, { "object b", objB } };

// example of unserializing
ClassForObjectA anotherObjA = null;
if(jsonMock.Contains("object a")) {
    anotherObjA = (ClassForObjA)jsonMock["object a"];
}
```