# All possible array initialization syntaxes

Tags: c#, arrays, syntax, array-initialization

What are all the array initialization syntaxes that are possible with C#?

Answer (score 974, accepted):

These are the current declaration and initialization methods for a simple array.

```
string[] array = new string[2]; // creates array of length 2, default values
string[] array = new string[] { "A", "B" }; // creates populated array of length 2
string[] array = { "A" , "B" }; // creates populated array of length 2
string[] array = new[] { "A", "B" }; // creates populated array of length 2
string[] array = ["A", "B"]; // creates populated array of length 2
```

Note that other techniques of obtaining arrays exist, such as the Linq `ToArray()` extensions on `IEnumerable<T>`.

Also note that in the declarations above, the first two could replace the `string[]` on the left with `var` (C# 3+), as the information on the right is enough to infer the proper type. The third line must be written as displayed, as array initialization syntax alone is not enough to satisfy the compiler's demands. The fourth could also use inference. The fifth line was introduced in C# 12 as collection expressions where the target type cannot be inferenced. It can also be used for spans and lists. If you're into the whole brevity thing, the above could be written as

```
var array = new string[2]; // creates array of length 2, default values
var array = new string[] { "A", "B" }; // creates populated array of length 2
string[] array = { "A" , "B" }; // creates populated array of length 2
var array = new[] { "A", "B" }; // created populated array of length 2
string[] array = ["A", "B"]; // creates populated array of length 2
```

Comment: The C#12 [Collection expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-12#collection-expressions) can also be used for Lists<> ect. and they are also nice to instantiate an empty Array/List like this: `string[] arr = []` or `List<string> list = []` [Additional Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-12.0/collection-expressions)

Comment: For completeness, `string[] array = new string[2] { "A", "B" };` also works. `string[] array = new string[3] { "A", "B" };` or `string[] array = new string[1] { "A", "B" };` are  errors because of length mismatch.

Answer (score 474):

The array creation syntaxes in C# that are *expressions* are:

```
new int[3]
new int[3] { 10, 20, 30 }
new int[] { 10, 20, 30 }
new[] { 10, 20, 30 }
```

In the first one, the size may be any non-negative integral value and the array elements are initialized to the default values.

In the second one, the size must be a constant and the number of elements given must match. There must be an implicit conversion from the given elements to the given array element type.

In the third one, the elements must be implicitly convertible to the element type, and the size is determined from the number of elements given.

In the fourth one the type of the array element is inferred by computing the best type, if there is one, of all the given elements that have types. All the elements must be implicitly convertible to that type. The size is determined from the number of elements given. This syntax was introduced in C# 3.0.

There is also a syntax which may only be used in a declaration:

```
int[] x = { 10, 20, 30 };
```

The elements must be implicitly convertible to the element type. The size is determined from the number of elements given.

> there isn't an all-in-one guide

I refer you to C# 4.0 specification, section 7.6.10.4 "Array Creation Expressions".

Comment: What is the `new[] { ... }` (or `new { ... }` for other types) syntax known as?

Comment: @BoltClock: The first syntax you mention is an "implicitly typed array creation expression". The second is an "anonymous object creation expression". You do not list the other two similar syntaxes; they are "object initializer" and "collection initializer".

Comment: Not exactly C# "syntax", but let's not forget (my personal favorite) `Array.CreateInstance(typeof(int), 3)`!

Comment: @Jeffrey: If we're going down that road,it starts getting silly.  E.g., `"1,2,3,4".split(',')`.

Comment: Then for multi-dimensional arrays, there exist "nested" notations like `new int[,] { { 3, 7 }, { 103, 107 }, { 10003, 10007 }, };`, and so on for `int[,,]`, `int[,,,]`, ...

Comment: @EricLippert:Is pure array or generic array like abc[] is faster than list because it is written in low level programming language?

Comment: @EricLippert First of all thank you so much for replying to my comment.I am trying to compare 2 unordered list by getting data from 2 different rdbms and then doing comparision in memory.which will be more efficient for this:Array or list?

Comment: @EricLippert You are right.I am sorry sir.Actually one of my colleague told me that generic array(t[]) are faster than list because generic or pure array are written in low level programming language.hence i am searching for this that it is true or not

Answer (score 133):

### Non-empty arrays

- `var data0 = new int[3]`
- `var data1 = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 }`
- `var data2 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }`
- `var data3 = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }`
- `var data4 = { 1, 2, 3 }` is not compilable. Use `int[] data5 = { 1, 2, 3 }` instead.

### Empty arrays

- `var data6 = new int[0]`
- `var data7 = new int[] { }`
- `var data8 = new [] { }`  and `int[] data9 = new [] { }` are not compilable.
- `var data10 = { }` is not compilable. Use `int[] data11 = { }`  instead.

### As an argument of a method

Only expressions that can be assigned with the `var` keyword can be passed as arguments.

- `Foo(new int[2])`
- `Foo(new int[2] { 1, 2 })`
- `Foo(new int[] { 1, 2 })`
- `Foo(new[] { 1, 2 })`
- `Foo({ 1, 2 })` is not compilable
- `Foo(new int[0])`
- `Foo(new int[] { })`
- `Foo({})` is not compilable

Comment: It would be good to more clearly separate the invalid syntaxes from the valid ones.

Answer (score 60):

```
Enumerable.Repeat(String.Empty, count).ToArray()
```

Will create array of empty strings repeated 'count' times. In case you want to initialize array with same yet special default element value. Careful with reference types, all elements will refer same object.

Comment: Yes, in `var arr1 = Enumerable.Repeat(new object(), 10).ToArray();` you get 10 references to the same object. To create 10 distinct objects, you can use `var arr2 = Enumerable.Repeat(/* dummy: */ false, 10).Select(x => new object()).ToArray();` or similar.

Answer (score 27):

```
var contacts = new[]
{
    new 
    {
        Name = " Eugene Zabokritski",
        PhoneNumbers = new[] { "206-555-0108", "425-555-0001" }
    },
    new 
    {
        Name = " Hanying Feng",
        PhoneNumbers = new[] { "650-555-0199" }
    }
};
```

Comment: How are you supposed to use this structure? Is it like a dictionary?

Comment: @R.Navega it's an ordinary array :)

Comment: @grooveplex It's an array of anonymous types. The anonymous types contain the members Name of type string and PhoneNumbers of type string[]. The types are inferred by the compiler.

Answer (score 27):

In case you want to initialize a fixed array of pre-initialized equal (non-`null` or other than `default`) elements, use this:

```
var array = Enumerable.Repeat(string.Empty, 37).ToArray();
```

Also please take part in [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/5078) discussion.

Answer (score 14):

#### Example to create an array of a custom class

Below is the class definition.

```
public class DummyUser
{
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
}
```

This is how you can initialize the array:

```
private DummyUser[] arrDummyUser = new DummyUser[]
{
    new DummyUser{
       email = "abc.xyz@email.com",
       language = "English"
    },
    new DummyUser{
       email = "def@email.com",
       language = "Spanish"
    }
};
```

Answer (score 11):

**Just a note**

The following arrays:

```
string[] array = new string[2];
string[] array2 = new string[] { "A", "B" };
string[] array3 = { "A" , "B" };
string[] array4 = new[] { "A", "B" };
```

Will be **compiled** to:

```
string[] array = new string[2];
string[] array2 = new string[] { "A", "B" };
string[] array3 = new string[] { "A", "B" };
string[] array4 = new string[] { "A", "B" };
```

Answer (score 10):

Repeat without [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query):

```
float[] floats = System.Array.ConvertAll(new float[16], v => 1.0f);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
int[] array = new int[4]; 
array[0] = 10;
array[1] = 20;
array[2] = 30;
```

or

```
string[] week = new string[] {"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday"};
```

or

```
string[] array = { "Sunday" , "Monday" };
```

and in multi dimensional array

```
    Dim i, j As Integer
    Dim strArr(1, 2) As String

    strArr(0, 0) = "First (0,0)"
    strArr(0, 1) = "Second (0,1)"

    strArr(1, 0) = "Third (1,0)"
    strArr(1, 1) = "Fourth (1,1)"
```

Comment: Hi, the last block of examples appear to be Visual Basic, the question asks for c# examples.

Answer (score 4):

```
For Class initialization:
var page1 = new Class1();
var page2 = new Class2();
var pages = new UIViewController[] { page1, page2 };
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of creating and initializing an array of objects.  This is similar to the [example which @Amol has posted above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39282581/279844), except this one uses constructors.  A dash of polymorphism sprinkled in, I couldn't resist.

```
IUser[] userArray = new IUser[]
{
    new DummyUser("abc@cde.edu", "Gibberish"),
    new SmartyUser("pga@lna.it", "Italian", "Engineer")
};
```

Classes for context:

```
interface IUser
{
    string EMail { get; }       // immutable, so get only an no set
    string Language { get; }
}

public class DummyUser : IUser
{
    public DummyUser(string email, string language)
    {
        m_email = email;
        m_language = language;
    }

    private string m_email;
    public string EMail
    {
        get { return m_email; }
    }

    private string m_language;
    public string Language
    {
        get { return m_language; }
    }
}

public class SmartyUser : IUser
{
    public SmartyUser(string email, string language, string occupation)
    {
        m_email = email;
        m_language = language;
        m_occupation = occupation;
    }

    private string m_email;
    public string EMail
    {
        get { return m_email; }
    }

    private string m_language;
    public string Language
    {
        get { return m_language; }
    }

    private string m_occupation;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

hi just to add another way:
from this page :
https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netcore-3.1

you can use this form If you want to Generates a sequence of integral numbers within a specified range strat 0 to 9:

```
using System.Linq
.....
public int[] arrayName = Enumerable.Range(0, 9).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

In C# 12, you will able to create an array like this : int[] positions = [1, 2, 3];

Really great !

Answer (score 1):

For the class below:

```
public class Page
{

    private string data;

    public Page()
    {
    }

    public Page(string data)
    {
        this.Data = data;
    }

    public string Data
    {
        get
        {
            return this.data;
        }
        set
        {
            this.data = value;
        }
    }
}
```

you can initialize the array of above object as below.

```
Pages = new Page[] { new Page("a string") };
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create dynamic arrays i.e. you can first ask the size of the array from the user before creating it.

```
Console.Write("Enter size of array");
int n = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

int[] dynamicSizedArray= new int[n]; // Here we have created an array of size n
Console.WriteLine("Input Elements");
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
     dynamicSizedArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}

Console.WriteLine("Elements of array are :");
foreach (int i in dynamicSizedArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

Trivial solution with expressions. Note that with NewArrayInit you can create just one-dimensional array.

```
NewArrayExpression expr = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(int), new[] { Expression.Constant(2), Expression.Constant(3) });
int[] array = Expression.Lambda<Func<int[]>>(expr).Compile()(); // compile and call callback
```

Answer (score 0):

To initialize an empty array, it should be `Array.Empty<T>()` in [dotnet 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.empty?view=net-5.0)

**For string**

```
var items = Array.Empty<string>();
```

**For number**

```
var items = Array.Empty<int>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is by calling a static function (for a static object) or any function for instance objects.  This can be used for member initialisation.

Now I've not tested all of this so I'll put what I've tested (static member and static function)

```
Class x {
    private static Option[] options = GetOptionList();
    private static Option[] GetOptionList() {

        return (someSourceOfData).Select(dataitem => new Option()
                 {field=dataitem.value,field2=dataitem.othervalue});
    }
}
```

What I'd love to know is if there is a way to bypass the function declaration.  I know in this example it could be used directly, but assume the function is a little more complex and can't be reduced to a single expression.

I imagine something like the following (but it doesn't work)

```
Class x {
    private static Option[] options = () => {
        Lots of prep stuff here that means we can not just use the next line
        return (someSourceOfData).Select(dataitem => new Option()
                 {field=dataitem.value,field2=dataitem.othervalue});
    }
}
```

Basically a way of just declaring the function for the scope of filling the variable.
I'd love it if someone can show me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

For multi-dimensional array in C# declaration & assign values.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        char[][] charArr = new char[][] { new char[] { 'a', 'b' }, new char[] { 'c', 'd' } };

        int[][] intArr = new int[][] { new int[] { 1, 2 }, new int[] { 3, 4 } };
    }

}
```

Comment: This question is asked more than 11 years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer

Comment: I was trying to create a multi-dimension array and retrieve a specified value like the one below, however when I attempted using the syntax provided by Microsoft in [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays) VS gave me a syntax error. In an effort to aid someone in the future, I posted to this question. 
`int[,] array2Da = new int[4, 2] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } }; Console.WriteLine(array2Da[1][1]); //error => array2Da is not null here`