# Why the following cannot compile?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
String s = new String({'h','e','l','l','o'});
```

I received the error:

> 1  Invalid expression term '{'

I thought `{'h','e','l','l','o'}` should be a character array, why did it fail to compile?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5678393/414076 and Section 7.6.10.4 of the language specification. Your specific example is only a legal array initialization syntax in conjunction with a variable declaration, which is notably missing in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
String s = new String(new[] {'h','e','l','l','o'});
```

The code you had before was not initializing an array correctly. Check out the MSDN article on [implicitly typed arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx) for more info.

You could also explicitly specify the type of the array:

```
String s = new String(new char[] {'h','e','l','l','o'});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
String s = new String(new char [] {'h','e','l','l','o'});
```