# How do I convert this VB.NET array expression to C#

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#, array-initialization

In VB.net, I can write:

```vb
If {"red", "blue"}.Contains("blue") Then Return True
```

and the `Contains` seems to be from Linq.Enumerable(Of T).

I'm having trouble converting it to C# - when I use an online conversion tool like the one from [Developer Fusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/), it gives me:

```cs
if ({"red", "blue"}.Contains("blue")) return true;
```

but it doesn't compile, saying it's unable to resolve the symbol `Contains` which isn't very helpful.  I'm sure it's a simple syntax issue, but I'm not sure what you call an example like this.

I don't need to instantiate the array, since I'm just using it to evaluate the expression inline.  This seems to be possible in VB.NET.  What do you call this - a static array? constant array? anonymous array? some combination of those listed?

I'd like to know how to write this in C#, and also what this is called (I'll update the question title and tags to better reflect what I'm asking when someone can answer that).  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be your direct conversion

```
if (new []{"red", "blue"}.Contains("blue")) return true;
```

Oh, it's called an [array initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-c-sharp-array-initialization-syntaxes)

Comment: Ok, so in C#, you _must_ instantiate the array?

Comment: @Lumirris - yes! initialization is explicit!

Comment: In both C# and VB the array is instantiated - it's just that VB allows you to omit the 'New'.