# Whats the difference between Declaring a variable (as new) and then initializing it and direct initializing it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have seen people use a couple of different way of initializing arrays:

```
string[] Meal = new string[]{"Roast beef", "Salami", "Turkey", "Ham", "Pastrami"};
```

or another way, also called initializing is:

```
string[] Meats = {"Roast beef", "Salami", "Turkey", "Ham", "Pastrami" };
```

What is the best way, and what is the major difference between both ways (including memory allocation)?

Comment: [Array Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573(v=vs.71).aspx) (quite old, but the language hasn't really changed here)

Comment: Even `var Meats = {"Roast beef", "Salami", "Turkey", "Ham", "Pastrami" };` is the same also.

Comment: @SonerGönül : yea I know about that.

Comment: You can't use the second syntax to change the value of an existing variable, but you *can* use the first syntax to do so.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no difference in both cases. Compiler generates the same bytecode (`newarr` OpCode):

```
public static void Main()
{
   string[] Meal = new string[] { "Roast beef", "Salami", "Turkey", "Ham", "Pastrami"};
   string[] Meats = { "Roast beef", "Salami", "Turkey", "Ham", "Pastrami" };
}
```

MSIL:

```
.entrypoint
  // Code size       100 (0x64)
  .maxstack  3
  .locals init ([0] string[] Meal,
           [1] string[] Meats,
           [2] string[] CS$0$0000)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.5
  IL_0002:  newarr     [mscorlib]System.String
  IL_0007:  stloc.2
  IL_0008:  ldloc.2
  IL_0009:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_000a:  ldstr      "Roast beef"
  IL_000f:  stelem.ref
  IL_0010:  ldloc.2
  IL_0011:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0012:  ldstr      "Salami"
  IL_0017:  stelem.ref
  IL_0018:  ldloc.2
  IL_0019:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_001a:  ldstr      "Turkey"
  IL_001f:  stelem.ref
  IL_0020:  ldloc.2
  IL_0021:  ldc.i4.3
  IL_0022:  ldstr      "Ham"
  IL_0027:  stelem.ref
  IL_0028:  ldloc.2
  IL_0029:  ldc.i4.4
  IL_002a:  ldstr      "Pastrami"
  IL_002f:  stelem.ref
  IL_0030:  ldloc.2
  IL_0031:  stloc.0
  IL_0032:  ldc.i4.5
  IL_0033:  newarr     [mscorlib]System.String
  IL_0038:  stloc.2
  IL_0039:  ldloc.2
  IL_003a:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_003b:  ldstr      "Roast beef"
  IL_0040:  stelem.ref
  IL_0041:  ldloc.2
  IL_0042:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0043:  ldstr      "Salami"
  IL_0048:  stelem.ref
  IL_0049:  ldloc.2
  IL_004a:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_004b:  ldstr      "Turkey"
  IL_0050:  stelem.ref
  IL_0051:  ldloc.2
  IL_0052:  ldc.i4.3
  IL_0053:  ldstr      "Ham"
  IL_0058:  stelem.ref
  IL_0059:  ldloc.2
  IL_005a:  ldc.i4.4
  IL_005b:  ldstr      "Pastrami"
  IL_0060:  stelem.ref
  IL_0061:  ldloc.2
  IL_0062:  stloc.1
  IL_0063:  ret
```

Comment: Wow this was very descriptive @Dmitry , BTW How can I check the MSIL ?

Comment: using the default utility in MS Visual Studio package ILDASM:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 4):

The two are identical, and will produce identical IL code.  The second is simply syntactic sugar for the first.

Answer (score 3):

Both of these ways are equivalent in the compiled code,  choose the one you think is clearest or easiest to read.

Answer (score 2):

See [Eric Lippert's response to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5678393/1438242).  In this specific scenario, they both produce the same compiled code and the same result.  The only difference between the two syntaxes is that **the second syntax can only be used in variable declaration**, which means you can't use it to change the value of an existing variable.  For instance:

```
// Compiles fine
string[] Meats = {"Roast beef", "Salami", "Turkey", "Ham", "Pastrami" };

// Causes compilation error
Meats = {"Roast beef", "Salami", "Turkey", "Ham", "Pastrami" };

// Also causes compilation error
string[] Meats2;
Meats2 = {"Roast beef", "Salami", "Turkey", "Ham", "Pastrami" };
```

Personally, I would suggest using the second syntax for variable declarations if you're explicitly declaring the type of your variable, as so:

```
string[] Meats = {"Roast beef", "Salami", "Turkey", "Ham", "Pastrami" };
```

I would recommend the first syntax if you tend to use the `var` keyword, as it makes it clearer what type you're expecting the results to be (readability) and forces the compiler to check for you as well, like so:

```
var Meats = new string[]{"Roast beef", "Salami", "Turkey", "Ham", "Pastrami" };
```

In general, it's best to pick one style and be consistent.

Comment: If you're down-voting, please explain why.  I'd like to understand what was wrong about my answer.