# difference between declaring arrays in c#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, arrays

While studying C#,I got the following doubt.Since arrays are reference types in C# when declared I think they are allocated on heap all the time.So when we declare array in following the ways:

```
int[] arr1 = {1,2,3};
int[] arr2 = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Is there any difference between them?

And can we declare array `int arr[100];` like in C++?(without initializing and without using new keyword)And then assign them value later.

Comment: Just look at this [Eric Lippert answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5678393/2316200), it have been asked before

Comment: `after this function returns you can still use arr2` What the heck are you talking about?

Comment: @bapusethi that is true in C++ not in C# i think

Comment: @bapusethi An array is a reference type, so it cannot be allocated on the stack.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Thanks,I got the answer for the first question.can we declare int arr[100]; in C# like we do in C++?(or similar syntax)

Comment: No zoomln unfortunatly you cant,you can assign other array to your new one.

Comment: C#, being a garbage collected language, allows you to *mostly* ignore memory allocation issues.  There *are* some issues that are important to think about, but most of that is handled for you if you properly handle `IDisposable` subclasses with `using` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Its the array initialization syntax

```
int[] arr1 = {1,2,3};
int[] arr2 = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] arr2 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

they are the same. In this case...

```
int[] arr2 = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

since you declared the size[3] after you must match the quantity.

check this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx

EDIT:

```
int[] MyArray = new int[100];
            int[] MyOtherArray = MyArray;
```

this is what you can do about your second question