# Check if object name equals "textbox" + numberarray.Any()?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

How would I be able to check the combination of `textbox + numbers.Any()` in one if statement such that it matches the name of the control?

```
foreach (Control con in this.Controls)
{
    if (con is TextBox)
    {
        if (con.Name == "textBox" + numbers.Any())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something");
        }
    }
}
```

These are the numbers:

```
string[] numbers = new string[5] { "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" };
```

Comment: `numbers.Any()` return true or false

Comment: Ah, now i get it, thanks :D

Comment: @MasterXD Stop editing "solved" into your title.  Such information doesn't belong their.  The question list already has a visual indication of questions with an accepted answer.  Your title should be for the title of your question, nothing else.

Comment: OH... Then i have some titles to edit :D Thanks for telling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Any()` overload with empty parameters return true if there exists something to enumerate. Furthermore its returns a boolean value, so if you concatenate that the way you have done with a string, your if condition looks like this:

```
if(con.Name == "textBoxTrue")
//or
if(con.Name == "textBoxFalse")
```

So you have to do like Oliver has shown. **Another (shorter) option is**:

```
if (numbers.Any(n => con.Name == "textBox" + n))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Something");
}
```

The entire `foreach` thing can be written in one line (this is where Linq helps):

```
foreach (var x in this.Controls
                      .OfType<TextBox>()
                      .Where(con => numbers.Any(n => con.Name == "textBox" + n)))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Something");
}
```

But if what you're doing is more complex stuff, then its better to write `foreach` as such for readability.

---

You can also take advantage of various array initialization syntaxes C# offers. Specifying the size when you're adding elements to array makes it little redundant. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-c-sharp-array-initialization-syntaxes). So it need be only:

```
var numbers = new[] { "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" }; //may replace var with string[]
//or
string[] numbers = { "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" };
```

Instead of

```
string[] numbers = new string[5] { "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" };
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
numbers.Select(n => string.Format("textBox{0}", n)).Contains(con.Name);
```

Comment: where should i place this exactly? I am not used to write my code like that.

Comment: I can only press "Answer Accepted" in 4 minutes? Why that exactly?

Comment: Cheers for the edit @Royi, can't type backtick on this mobile!

Comment: @MasterXD So youll able to see at least others peoples answers.

Comment: @MasterXD, I guess it's to give time for other answers

Comment: I may be mistaken, but won't this fail if `numbers` contains both 1 and 10?

Comment: @Tharwen no it won't fail.  `Enumerable.Contains` on will only return true for an exact match.  Unlike `string.Contains` which would return true for `"textBox10".Contains("textBox1")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this :

```
var a="textBox5".Split(new string[]{"textBox"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

if (a.Length==2) && numbers.Contains(a[1])) 
{
//  exists...
}
```