# Convert an object to a single item array of object (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays

Some functions only accept arrays as arguments but you want to assign a single object to them. For example to assign a primary key column for a `DataTable` I do this:

```
DataColumn[] time = new DataColumn[1];
time[0] = timeslots.Columns["time"];
timeslots.PrimaryKey = time;
```

This seems cumbersome, so basically I only need to convert a `DataColumn` to a `DataColumn[1]` **array**. Is there any easier way to do that ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can write it using the array initializer syntax:

```
timeslots.PrimaryKey = new[] { timeslots.Columns["time"] }
```

This uses type inference to infer the type of the array and creates an array of whatever type timeslots.Columns["time"] returns.

If you would prefer the array to be a different type (e.g. a supertype) you can make that explicit too

```
timeslots.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { timeslots.Columns["time"] }
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also write in one line with array initializer:

```
timeslots.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { timeslots.Columns["time"] };
```

Check this out: [All possible C# array initialization syntaxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-c-sharp-array-initialization-syntaxes)

Answer (score 2):

```
timeslots.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { timeslots.Columns["time"] };
```

Answer (score 1):

Drawing on the answers above, I created this extension method which is very helpful and saves me a lot of typing.

```
/// <summary>
/// Convert the provided object into an array 
/// with the object as its single item.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the object that will 
/// be provided and contained in the returned array.</typeparam>
/// <param name="withSingleItem">The item which will be 
/// contained in the return array as its single item.</param>
/// <returns>An array with <paramref name="withSingleItem"/> 
/// as its single item.</returns>
public static T[] ToArray<T>(this T withSingleItem) => new[] { withSingleItem };
```

Answer (score 1):

I liked @rory.ap's extension method answer, but I refactored it to have simpler comments and also to handle nulls better.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Creates an array with an object as its single item, or an empty array if the object is null.
/// </summary>
public static T[] ToArray<T>(this T? withSingleItem) =>
   withSingleItem == null ? Array.Empty<T>() : new[] { withSingleItem };
```

Comment: It would be nice if the .NET team would add a Array.One<T>(T value) method. I'd prefer that to polluting my intellisense with more indiscriminate extension methods.

Having said that, which is better? "item.ToArray()", "Array.One(item)", or "new[]{item}"?

Just realised that in C# 12 we can now just use "[item]" to create an array from an item.