# C# dynamic array initialisation [advantage?]

Tags: c#, arrays, array-initialization

I had just started learning C# and using `Tutorials Point` to do this. In the section on arrays, I keep seeing arrays declared as

```
string[] sarray = { "Hello", "From", "Tutorials", "Point" };
```

Or other times like this:

```
int [] marks = new int[5]  { 99,  98, 92, 97, 95 };
```

Coming from c++, the first method of declaration wasn't all that new to me, but the second one is the one I don't understand. The question is if the array is going to dynamically initialised, then why use the brace enclosed initializer list to specify the contents of the array?

Is there an advantage to initialising that second one the way it has been done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [All possible C# array initialization syntaxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-c-sharp-array-initialization-syntaxes)

Comment: The difference between the first and second example is syntax. There are several styles to initialize arrays. I would recommend using a [`List(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) since it behaves more like the C++ `vector` type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No advantage at all. It's a coding-preference thing.

You can even leave out just the size portion such as:

```
int[] marks = new int[] {99, 98, 92, 97, 95};
```

Check out the MSDN for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: you don't even need the int[] part on the right, `int[] abc = new[] { 99, 98, 92, 97, 95 };` works just fine

Comment: Ok thanks for this, I was just thinking it had something to do with being able to pass one to a function not being able to do that with the other due to the way they have both been initialised

Answer (score 3):

The first statement is implicitly the same as

```
string[] sarray = new string[5] { "Hello", ... };
```

There is no advantage to one style over the other, save personal preference. I would tend to write the second statement as

```
var marks = new [] { 99, 98, ... };
```