# Array initialization in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

In C#, the array can be initialized by the following syntax

```
string[]arr = {"text1","text2"}; // this works
```

why does the following not work

```
string[]arr1;
arr1={"phrase1","phrase2"};//Does not compile.
```

Comment: Because in the second snippet you're not really *initializing* a variable, you're trying to assign a value. The first syntax is special.

Comment: The first syntax actually implies `new string[] { ... }`.

Comment: That syntax is just compiler sugar. It doesn't understand how to do the second syntax, so it doesn't work. Simple as that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string[] arr = { "text1", "text2" };
```

This works because this is a special syntax only allowed when first initializing an array variable (personally I didn't even know it existed).

If you want to later assign a new array to a variable, you need to say `new`:

```
arr = new string[] { "text1", "text2" };
```

You can also say just `new []` and the compiler will figure out the type for you.

Comment: In your first example Resharper would mark the `new string[]` as unnecessary (if you had included it), because of this shorthand notation.

Answer (score 3):

The second syntax is wrong according to the C# specification: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Check that link as well for more examples about how to initialize an array:
[All possible C# array initialization syntaxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-c-sharp-array-initialization-syntaxes)

Comment: +0: while links looks reasonable you should inline summary of external links in the post. I.e. in this case one or two sentences quotes from the specification would make answer much better. Local (SO) links is more ok, but it is still good practice to provide summary + link rather than just link (i.e. if other post deleted most people will not be able to see it).

Answer (score 0):

It's all about allocating memory.
The first is short for:

```
string[]arr = new string[]{"text1","text2"};
```

So the compiler knows in the same statement the number of elements to allocate using the `new` keyword.

The second is just wrong syntax.
If you want to do it in two steps:

```
string[]arr1; // defines array(pointer)
arr1=new string[]{"phrase1","phrase2"}; // again when `new` is used for dynamic memory allocation, the size is available.
```

Comment: you cannot assign strings to an int! new int[] {"phrase1", "phrase2"};

Comment: you now fixed it... :)