# Got surprised knowing that C# compiler can infer less informative declaration

Tags: c#, arrays

Consider the following code snippet to follow my mind chronologically. The commented statements cannot be compiled.

```
    var data1 = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };
    var data2 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

    var data3 = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    var data4 = new[] { 1, 2, 3.0f };
```

The simplification done for `data3` and `data4` is understandable.

```
    int[] data5 = { 1, 2, 3 };
    //var data6 = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Unable to infer the declaration for `data6` is understandable.

```
    var data7 = new int[] { };
    //var data8 = new [] { }; 
    //int[] data9 = new [] { };
```

Unable to infer the declaration for `data8` is also understandable.

What I don't understand is why `data9` which is more informative cannot be compiled while `data10` that is less informative can be compiled.

```
    int[] data10 = { };
    //var data11 = { };
```

Declaring `data11` that cannot be compiled is also understandable.

Comment: Without being as precise as Eric Lippert would, I think it's fair to say that *inference occurs on the right-hand side of that assignment, not the left-hand side.*  In other words, you need a target `var` in which to put the inferred item; specifying the target type is not going to do it, if there's not enough information on the right-hand side of the equals sign to figure out what the expression type is.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I think the question is about `int[] data9 = new [] { };` vs `int[] data10 = { };`, second one is allowed, but not the first one.

Comment: @Habib: `int[] data9 = new [] { };` looks like a type error to me.  `new [] { };` is not an `int[]`.  The type of the expression on the right-hand side of the equals must be compatible with the declared type on the left-hand side.  Again, inference is not occurring on the left-hand side of the equals.

Comment: `int[] data9 = { };` this would work but adding new will not compile
`var data7 = new int[] { };` compiles because compiler infers type to be of `Int32`

Comment: @RobertHarvey, with or without the space, the compiler error is "No best type found for implicitly-typed array."

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: @DJKRAZE, he already knows that work work. See: `int[] data10` from the question text. @RobertHarvey, your comment text changed since I saw it. It was originally much vaguer (syntax error, or some such thing).

Comment: `var data11 = new { };` compiles as anonymous type

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I am totally familiar with what he's trying to do 
I know when to use and when not to use especially when I have fellow developers whom think that code won't compile because one does not initialize an array size for example that's why `string[] mystring = { };` will compile and initially have mystring[0] will have a length of `0` if this code were used for example and it's easier to dynamically size it if one were to fill / populate it from a List<T>  for example

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Are you responding to the right person?

Comment: sorry @RobertHarvey I meant that for Anthony Pegram no biggie

Answer (score 2):

C# is of type of language that cannot infer types from context. It means that it can extract types only from the expression outside, not vice versa.

In other words, the phenomenon you have shown is identical to the fact that the compiler cannot choose the correct overload in the following case:

```
int foo();
string foo();

string x = foo();
```

However it can choose the correct overload in the following case:

```
void bar(int x);
void bar(string x);

string x;
bar(x);
```

**Edit:** Servy commented that lambda expression is an exception for that rule. For example:

```
var a = new Func<int, bool>(a => a == 1);
```

the compiler cannot infer the type of "a => a == 1" without inferring it from the context.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying here, but the way you're saying it is not at all clear.

Comment: Your first statement isn't quite correct.  They try hard to avoid inferring types from context wherever possible, but they haven't succeeded entirely in that regard.  The type of lambdas is dependent on their context.  `() => false;` has no type, you need to assign it to something like an `Action` for the compiler to deduce its type.

Answer (score 2):

The cases where there is a `new` keyword present, are usual expressions that can be used by themselves in any context where an expression is required. You use them for declarations with assignment, but they can be used in other contexts, for example:

```
return new[] { 3 };
```

or:

```
Call(new[] { 3 });
```

and so on. In these `new` array expressions, the type must be clear from the expression itself. This is required even when there is a variable declaration on the left.

The case `data9` therefore, with `int[] data9 = new [] { };` is illegal because the expression `new[] { }` is illegal. It is somewhat like:

```
object related9 = someBoolean ? "Yes" : new Exception();
```

which is also illegal because the expression `someBoolean ? "Yes" : new Exception()` is illegal in itself, with incompatible types. There is a declaration of type `object`, but that does not make the right-hand side legal.

---

The examples `data5` and `data10` show a completely unrelated syntax for array variable declaration.

```
int[] data5 = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Here the right-hand side of the `=` operator is ***not*** an expression in itself. This syntax requires a declaration with explicit type on the left of the `=` sign (so `data6` is not OK). This syntax is related to *object initializers* and *collection initializers* and was introduced in the C# language together with them, whereas the `new[] { ... }` syntax is a bit older.

---

You should see [this answer by Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5678393/1336654), then read the official C# Language Specification.