# What does new [] mean

Tags: c#

There is a code where that reads something from the XML and loads it into dictionary.
Pls find the code below. I need to understand what `new [] {header}` does.

what is `new []` doing here.Thanks in advance.

```
var headers = _doc.GetElementsByTagName("Header");
var header = headers[0];

_dict.Add("Header_" + headerId, new [] {header});
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx

Comment: Relevant: [All possible C# array initialization syntaxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-c-sharp-array-initialization-syntaxes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an [implicitly typed array creation expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx) - it lets the compiler infer the array type, a bit like using `var` but for arrays. So in your case, it's equivalent to:

```
_dict.Add("Header_" + headerId, new XmlNode[] { header });
```

It was added in C# 3 along with `var` to support anonymous types. For example, you can write:

```
var people = new[]
{
    new { Name = "Jon", Home = "Reading" },
    new { Name = "Gareth", Home = "Cambridge" }    
};
```

You couldn't write that as *explicitly* typed array creation expression, because the type of the array elements doesn't have a name.

Answer (score 2):

It adds a new Array with the contents of header.

Answer (score 1):

It is just for creating a new array. Since you use a collection initializer, The compiler knows the type from `headers[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You allocate a new array. The compiler decides of which type.

Answer (score 1):

new [] {header} is just creating a new instance of an array. The type of items the array is about to store is the type of the header object. There is no need to define for example: new string[] { "some string" }, a simple new[] { "some string" } is enough to create an array instance of type String.