# What does the new[] {string} syntax mean?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm studying a book with Membership topic in ASP.NET MVC and I found syntax, I cannot trace (and not explained in the book), which is:

```
new[] {"string"}
```

like in:

```
Roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] {userName}, new[] {roleName});
```

Per MDSN library I see Roles.AddUsersToRoles method takes two string arrays as arguments, so likely this is a shorthand or would this have some additional functionality?

Comment: `new {userName}` presumably is a typo for `new [] {userName}`?

Comment: yes it was a typo, thank you Blorgbeard, and Grant Winney - also a right edit, many thanks.

Comment: Fyi, there is also an overload for single user and rolename strings. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.addusertorole(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does new \[\] mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599213/what-does-new-mean)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is [Implicitly Typed Arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx) syntax.

> You can create an implicitly-typed array in which the **type of the
>   array instance is inferred from the elements specified** in the array
>   initializer.

This

```
string[] stringArray = new[] {"string"};
```

is same as :

```
string[] stringArray = new string[] {"string"};
```

Other thing to note, the method [`Roles.AddUsersToRoles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.adduserstoroles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) accepts two parameters of string type array *(and not a string)*.

```
public static void AddUsersToRoles(
    string[] usernames,
    string[] roleNames
)
```

Comment: ok, great thank you Habib, will accept your answer shortly :)

Answer (score 2):

```
new string[1] { "string" }
```

You can omit the array size because the compiler can count the number of elements for you:

```
new string[ ] { "string" }
```

You can also omit the array element type because the compiler can infer it from the values provided:

```
new       [ ] { "string" }
```

---

But do *not* get this mixed up with initializers for [anonymous types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx). These do not have the angle brackets `[]` after `new`:

```
new { StringProperty = "string" }
```

or:

```
// string StringProperty;
new { StringProperty }
```