# can we initialize array by calling parameterized constructor

Tags: c#

How to initialize an array of objects by calling the parameterized constructor of the class

Example:

```
class a
{
    int val;

    //def
    public a()
    {
    }

    //with param
    public a(int value)
    {
        val = value;
    }
}
```

How to initialize a dynamic array of the above class by using its constructor

eg:

```
a[] dyArray = new a[size];  // how to call constructor to initialize a value 
                            // other than looping each element and initialize 
                            // it? say, with value 10;
```

Is there any other standard way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [All possible C# array initialization syntaxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-c-sharp-array-initialization-syntaxes)

Comment: You can't do it without looping or explicitly providing every element.

Comment: okay. I too think so, just asked to know any solution available or not. Thanks @Enigmativity

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault - This isn't a duplicate. This is a different question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about this?

```
var darray = (new int[dzise]).Select(x=>new a(10)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a generic list instead you can create the collection and initialise a value:

```
List<a> aList = new List<a>
{
    new a(10)
};
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: yea, for a list. Thanks for that answer

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
 a[] dyArray = new a[]{
     new a(1),
     new a(2)
 };
```

Comment: but it is a dynamic array, so this wont be possible in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

The good old way is like this:

```
a** dyn_arr_ptr = new a*[size];
for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
  dyn_arr_ptr[i] = new a(10); // or it could "new a(i)" more flexibility here in parameter value per instance
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).