# How to configure two array, the first containing the numbers that will be divided, and the second contains the numbers that Divisible the first one

Tags: c#

How to configure two array, the first containing the numbers that will be divided, and the second contains the numbers that Divisible the first one

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - can you give an example?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-c-sharp-array-initialization-syntaxes

Comment: i want  such this  4/2 or 8/4 or 9/3 or 12/3

Answer (score 0):

Similar thing you are looking for?

```
        List<Tuple<int, int>> recs = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
        recs.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(4, 2));
        recs.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(8, 4));
        recs.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(9, 3));
        recs.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(12, 3));
```

Comment: The user was asking for arrays, you posted a List. A description of your solution would be nice.

Comment: how can i put this tuple into textbox