# create array on the fly with random length containing elements initialized with fixed value

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code :

```
    for(int i=0;i<???;i++)
    {    
        ...
    }
    tb.SetWidths(new int[] { 50, 50, 50,.... });
```

The problem is:

- The amout of array elemens must be equal to "i"
- I also want to set the value to all these elements to 50

How can i do that?

**Tb is an object from itextsharp, i'm using it to draw tables on pdf files**

Comment: Would you like to provide some information about tb ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "amout of array elements"? Can you give an example?

Comment: he means that the length is going to be random  - I changed the title  waiting for peer review of the edit :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess something like that would work for you? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34379619/986160)

if count is random you can do:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int count = rand.Next(1, 101); // creates a number between 1 and 100
```

( 50 is the fixed value for all 'count' elements)

```
int[] array = Enumerable
              .Repeat(50, count)
              .ToArray();
```

then you can do:

```
 tb.SetWidths(array);
```

Comment: Looks like you saved me, i'm testing your solution

Comment: @Liev04 Thanks for accepting

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you've put little to no effort into this exercise.

By simply Googling ***"c# define array of size"*** I found the following code:

```
 int i = random number;
 int[] myArray = new int [i];
```

Next, in order to populate the array with a certain integer, you simply loop through it:

```
    for(int x = 0; x < myArray.Length; x++){
        myArray[x] = 50;
    }
```