# How to have empty array as part of implict array in C#

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

This declaration causes an error because the last item is empty.

```
  var foo = new[] {
                 new [] {1, 2, 3},
                 new [] {3, 4, 5},
                 new [] {}
                 };
```

I understand that in general the compiler would need all these arrays to be of the same (anonymous) type, but it seems like it should allow "empty" as a special case and type it like all the others.

Is there some way to declare the above so that I can have an empty array along with the non-empty ones?

Michael

Comment: It cannot determine the Type of the elements. (because it has no elements)

Answer (score 7):

```
new [] {1, 2, 3}
```

is shorthand for

```
new int[] { 1,2,3 }
```

The compiler can figure out it has to be `int` because the array contains ints.
But if you say

```
new [] { }
```

since the array is empty, the Type cannot be determined. So you have to explicitly tell the compiler what the Type is:

```
var foo = new[] {
             new [] {1, 2, 3},
             new [] {3, 4, 5},
             new int [] {}
             };
```

Answer (score 5):

Sure, just make it an `int[]`:

```
int[][] foo = new[] {
         new [] {1, 2, 3},
         new [] {3, 4, 5},
         new int[] {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can if you iniltialise to a specific type:

```
        var foo = new int[][] {
             new int[] {1, 2, 3},
             new int[] {3, 4, 5},
             new int[] {}
             };
```

Comment: Where is the cast?

Answer (score 0):

Creating an empty array implicitly is not possible.
As @Dennis_E said "since the array is empty, the Type cannot be determined. "

You can refer to [All possible C# array initialization syntaxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-c-sharp-array-initialization-syntaxes)

Quoting from related part:

**Empty arrays**

```
...
var data8 = new [] { } and int[] data9 = new [] { } are not compilable.
...
```

And maybe to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx) -which gives less details btw-

Answer (score 0):

if you dont wanna explicitly write the type, you can use linq to filter the last array

```
var foo = new [] {
    new [] {1, 2, 3},
    new [] {3, 4, 5},
    new [] {0}.Where(e => false).ToArray()
};
```

this way it would work event if you has to change this code to:

```
var foo = new[] {
    new [] { new { N = 1 }, new { N = 2 }, new { N = 3} },
    new [] { new { N = 3 }, new { N = 4 }, new { N = 5} },
    new [] { new { N = 0 } }.Where(e => false).ToArray()
};
```