# What is the Difference Between Assigning Values to Arrays once Declared or Creating and Initializing an Array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

In tutorials, I've been seeing that there are two ways to assign values to an array in C#.

First method is:

```
double[] values = {23.245, 14.22,12.00};
```

Second method is:

```
double[] values = new double[] {23.245, 14.22, 12.00};
```

I would appreciate it if someone explained to me the difference between the two.

Cheers.

Comment: I disagree. The other one was asking for the need of the "new" keyword. I know what the new is for. I understand what new is for. I just wanted to know if there was any difference without using it.

Comment: This link can be useful to:
[All possible C# array initialization syntaxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-c-sharp-array-initialization-syntaxes)

Comment: The answers on the duplicate cover this well: both forms  are absolutely the same.

Comment: why you mark an answer that is exactly the same with the answer in a question that you said different with yours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first uses the concept of array initializers. It's a syntactic sugar. For further info, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573(v=vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely no difference...

```
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.3    
IL_0001:  newarr      System.Double
IL_0006:  dup         
IL_0007:  ldtoken     <PrivateImplementationDetails>.DBF4DA99AFD5E0399193CCEAA18D1DC95D64CC38
IL_000C:  call        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.InitializeArray
IL_0011:  pop         
IL_0012:  ret
```

That's what it will be compiled down to, using either statement