# Difference in array initialization with and without new operator

Tags: c#, initialization, new-operator

I've seen [All possible C# array initialization syntaxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-c-sharp-array-initialization-syntaxes) which shows several different ways to initialize an array.

Does the following initialization creates an instance that is different in some ways compared to one created with regular call with `new` ?

Initialization:

```
string[] strArray = {"one","two","three"};
```

Compared to `string[] strArray = new String[] {"one","two","three"};`

Comment: have you tried it? What did you get?

Comment: What do you mean does it create instance? Did you try it and get an object that you can use?

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov: That's very brave of you, but now you've gone and made the very first sentence of my answer sound strange in hindsight :(

Comment: @BoltClock I've tried to make question sensible (and not duplicate) and keep both your and user3185569 answers valid. I see that I've lost "is it even initilized" spirit that is covered by part of your question - not really sure if I can come up with sane way of asking that part so :).  I've closed it as duplicate first, but careful reading showed that this particular aspect is actually not covered in the "All possible C# array initialization syntaxes".

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov: Yeah, that's OK. It's still a good edit all around :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a syntactic sugar. The compiler transforms this:

```
string[] strArray = {"one","two","three"};
```

To This:

```
string[] expr_07 = new string[] {
            "one",
            "two",
            "three"
        };
```

Above output is using Roslyn C# compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize something that's not there. So yes, a new instance does get created, in the exact same way as though you *had* written the `new` operator. It's just a convenience provided by the language for when you're initializing an array at the same time that you're declaring it so you aren't *forced* to write it out (when doing it in a separate statement, the `new` operator is required because the compiler can't assume you haven't already assigned an array reference to the variable beforehand — the very bare minimum you can get away with in a separate statement is `strArray = new[] {...};`).