# What does new[] {a,b} mean and create?

Tags: c#, new-operator

I found this code

```
Stream foo() 
{
  ...
  return new MemoryStream(new[] { a, b });
}
```

and can guess what it does, but cannot find an explanation why the type definition `byte[]` can be omitted.
I looked at msdn c# [new](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/fa0ab757.aspx) explanation, but that is too simple there.

Comment: It creates a `MemoryStream` instance which contains two bytes: `a` and `b`

Comment: The type of the array can be derived from the arguments which are both bytes, so the array is a `Byte[]`. This  is an [implicitly typed array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-c-sharp-array-initialization-syntaxes

Comment: You ought to have included the definition for `a` and `b`!

Comment: @TaW : yes, I ought to have ;). But I was unsure if the possible c'tors of `MemoryStream` or the actual type of a and b played the major role.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> You can create an implicitly-typed array in which the type of the array instance is inferred from the elements specified in the array initializer. The rules for any implicitly-typed variable also apply to implicitly-typed arrays.

Taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx

Answer (score 4):

> I can guess what it does

You are right, it is the same as `new byte[] { a, b }`

> I cannot find an explanation why the type definition `byte[]` can be omitted

The reason it can be omitted is that both `a` and `b` are of type `byte`. The compiler is smart enough to figure out that you meant to create an array of `byte`s, so it does not ask you to specify the type explicitly.

Microsoft explains this shortcut [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573(v=vs.71).aspx). The idea is similar to omitting the type in declarations that use `var`, when the actual type can be inferred from initialization context.

Comment: other than the `shortcut` link, everything else makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

The type definition can be omitted because it can be inferred from the type of the objects in the list.

The C# compiler does a lot of work analysing the code as it compiles to check that what you write is valid and will execute as you intend. You can still make mistakes, but (hopefully) fewer than in languages like c or C++.

Answer (score 0):

with that , basically you create an array of objects implicitly!