# Is there any difference between new int[0] and new int[]{}

Tags: c#

I want to inizialize a new int array.

What are the advantages of:

```
var myNewArray = new int[]{};
```

And:

```
var myNewArray = new int[0];
```

Which one should I prefer over the other, or is it just a matter of code-style?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-c-sharp-array-initialization-syntaxes

Comment: @Bartosz thanks for the link. However, this is about initializing an array with items. I specifically wan't an empty array.

Comment: No difference. But starting with NET4.6, the preferred way is to use [`Array.Empty<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906179(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns a singleton instance.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks a lot! I knew of Enumerable.Empty but somehow overlooked Array<T>.Empty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no difference. Both produce the same IL:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  newarr      System.Int32
IL_0007:  stloc.0     // myNewArray
IL_0008:  ret
```