# What's the difference of the ways of array initialization?

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-core, coreclr

What's the difference of the two ways of array initialization? Are the same in all aspects?

using the `new` operator:

```
string[] arr = new array[3] {"a","b","c"};
```

and do not use the `new` operator:

```
string[] arr = {"a","b","c"};
```

Comment: Second way is shorter. It is the difference.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5678244/7565574. The latter one is just syntactical sugar which is basically internally converted to the first expression.

Comment: The relevant part of the C# language specification: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/arrays.md#array-initializers