# C# Convert Vector3d/Point3d to double[]

Tags: c#, vector, double

I need a double[] and I have a Point3d or a Vector3d. How can I convert a Point or a Vector to a double[]?
I create the Point and the Vector with following Code:

```
Point3d pos1 = new Point3d();
Point3d pos2 = new Point3d();
GetPosition(out pos1, out pos2);
Vector3d a = new Vector3d(pos1.X, pos1.Y, pos1.Z);

double[] move_mapped = new double[3];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All possible C# array initialization syntaxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-c-sharp-array-initialization-syntaxes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as you instantiated the `Vector3d`:

```
double[] move_mapped = new double[] {pos1.X, pos1.Y, pos1.Z};
```

or with the shorter array initializer

```
double[] move_mapped = {pos1.X, pos1.Y, pos1.Z};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[]` initializer syntax, like this:

```
double[] move_mapped = new double[] {
    pos1.X, pos1.Y, pos1.Z
};
```

The same syntax works for `Vector3d`. You can also use a "shortcut" syntax:

```
var move_mapped = new[] {a.X, a.Y, a.Z};
```