# How do i Initialize T[] arr kind of array using for loop

Tags: c#, .net

How can I initialize array for this generic class please help

```
 public class MarvellousArray<T>
 {
    private T[] array;

    public MarvellousArray(int size)
    {
        array = new T[size];
    }
    public void Accept()
    {

        var i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {

        }
    }
    public void Display()
    {

    } 
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to initialize the array using for loop

Comment: In the loop just assign the elements: `array[i] = MakeTheValue(…)`

Comment: Also a bit puzzled about what the use for this might be, but this code does not have any compile time issues. I've just tried it by making an instance:
`[TestMethod]
        public void Aaa()
        {
            var ma = new MarvellousArray<int>(3);
            ma.Accept();
        }`

and using it by inserting this into the loop's body: `Debug.Print(array[i].ToString());`

No issues!

Comment: Nothing is Working

Comment: array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());    This syntax is giving me error

Comment: how should the compiler know that at runtime you instantiated an array of int? for the compiler it is an array of T, you cannot just assign an int to T when T could be anything.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand what you mean... You could do this if you need to `new` `T`

```
public class MarvellousArray<T>
   where T : new()
{
   private readonly T[] _array;

   public MarvellousArray(int size)
   {
      _array = new T[size];

      for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
         _array[i] = new T();

   }

   ...
```

or just `default` which will be `null` for reference types

```
public class MarvellousArray<T>
{
   private readonly T[] _array;

   public MarvellousArray(int size)
   {
      _array = new T[size];

      for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
         _array[i] = default(T);

   }

   ...
```

Comment: However, initializing an array with its element‘s default value seems futile to me as this what arrays are already initialized to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initialize any array, there is the whole array Initilazier Syntax:
[All possible array initialization syntaxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-array-initialization-syntaxes)

The question is really what you want to Initialize it **with**.

The default value? ckuri pointed out that in most cases Array are initialied with that already.

A Specific value?

```
public static void setAll(int[] array, int value){
  for(int i = 0; i<array.Lenght;i++)
    array[i]=value;
}
```

I wrote this from memory. I am unsure if it was Size or Lenght with arrays. You could improve it with stuff like generics. Or a integer variable on how many times you want the value written.

Do you want them of a minimim size? Use List[T] and just define the minimum size with the constructor overload.

The values of another Array? List.AddRange is there for that.

Do you look for Lazy Initializsation? Then look at Lazy[T]. Alterantively you could write your class Array accessors. And initialize a empte value before you hand it out. Same way people do it with properties.