# Assigning values without initializing C#

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization

May I know the difference, if I can assign values to a array by

```
int [] marks = { 99,  98, 92, 97, 95};
```

Why do I see someone write this?

```
int [] marks = new int[]  { 99,  98, 92, 97, 95};
```

What is the difference?

Second question, since int is a primitive type, I can make an instance by

```
int i;
```

But I can see someone write like

```
int i = new int();
```

What is the difference again? Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is no difference the two ways of initializing an array. First approach is simpler in terms of writing a code. It offers you syntactical sugar but it does not initialize the array in different way.

Comment: The int is just a keyword in the background it mean Int32 structure. Try it out! Click in the int keyword and press F12

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-array-initialization-syntaxes there are lotsa other ways, u know.

Comment: with `int i = new int();` you cannot initialize with a given integer value, but with `int i` you can do..`int i = 9`

Comment: The shorter initializer syntax is more recent. Old-school is more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

General answer is that `a)` in `C#` you can achieve the same result in few ways
and `b)` not all ways were available from the beginning.

For `b)` there are two parts:

- code that has been written before new ways were added
- new code written with old habbits - new ways are not always better than the old ones, they just look better :)

## Re: array

Have a look at [Array Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays#array-initialization) in *Single-Dimensional Arrays (C# Programming Guide)*.

[Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) is also relevant.

Also, in [Array Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator#array-creation) from *new operator (C# reference)* shows 3 ways (and that's not all the ways):

```
var a = new int[3] { 10, 20, 30 };
var b = new int[] { 10, 20, 30 };
var c = new[] { 10, 20, 30 };
```

There even is a Question here about all possible ways: [All possible array initialization syntaxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-array-initialization-syntaxes#5678244).

---

## Re: new int

There are two parts in the answer:

1. With `int i;` (just a declaration) you cannot use before you initialise it.
2. There are multiple ways to initialise variables, as with arrays.

Have a look at [Initializing value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types#initializing-value-types) in *Value types (C# Reference)*.

You can read there:

> You can, of course, have the declaration and the initialisation in the same statement as in the following examples:
>
> ```
> int myInt = new int();
> ```
>
> –or–
>
> ```
>  int myInt = 0;
> ```

For default values specifically, have a look at [Default values table (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/default-values-table). You can see there that you can also:

```
int a = default(int);
```

and from `C#` 7.1 even

```
int a = default;
```