# Declaring an Array from a Class in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, class, declare

I want to create an Array of **"Highscore"** objects that I defined with a class.
I'm always getting a NullReferenceException when I try to set or read the Value of a specific Array content.

It does work when I use a single Highscore object instead of an Array.

It also does work when I use an integer array instead of an Highscore Array.

**Code**

```
class Highscore
{
    public int score;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Highscore[] highscoresArray = new Highscore[10];
        highscoresArray[0].score = 12;
        Console.WriteLine(highscoresArray[0].score);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

System.NullReferenceException:

highscoresArray[] was null.

Comment: `Highscore[] highscoresArray = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => new Highscore()).ToArray();`

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-array-initialization-syntaxes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in this code:

```
Highscore[] highscoresArray = new Highscore[10];
```

you instantiate an array of Highscore objects but you do not instantiate each object in the array.

you need to then do

```
for(int i = 0; i < highscoresArray.Length; i++)
    highscoresArray[i]  = new Highscore();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a Highscore to the array first, for example:

```
highscoresArray[0] = new Highscore();
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you've created an array, set its length, but never actually *instantiated* any of its elements. One way to do so would be:

```
Highscore[] highscoresArray = new Highscore[10];
highscoresArray[0] = new Highscore();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to initialize every item of the array:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < highscoresArray.length; i++)
 {
      highscoresArray[i] = new Highscore();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

.. Or use a Struct

```
struct Highscore
{
    public int score;
}
```

Comment: What are the dis/advantages of a struct?

Comment: @JoshuaDrake Specifically in this case - no initialization required.

Comment: The comment came from the review queue, we prefer answers to include the why, and not just the code.