# Why use the "new" syntax for a C# array?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, syntax, new-operator

I see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-array-initialization-syntaxes) that there are four permissible ways to initialise an array in C#. Taken from the accepted answer:

```
string[] array = new string[2]; // creates array of length 2, default values
string[] array = new string[] { "A", "B" }; // creates populated array of length 2
string[] array = { "A" , "B" }; // creates populated array of length 2
string[] array = new[] { "A", "B" }; // created populated array of length 2
```

The linked answer clarifies that you can also make the above expressions terser, with the exception of the third, using the `var` keyword:

```
var array = new string[2]; // creates array of length 2, default values
var array = new string[] { "A", "B" }; // creates populated array of length 2
string[] array = { "A" , "B" }; // creates populated array of length 2
var array = new[] { "A", "B" }; // created populated array of length 2
```

My question is: why would you ever wish to use the `new` syntax for an array? Is there any performance benefit to using either `var array = new string[] { "A", "B" }` instead of `string[] array = { "A" , "B" }`?

Comment: Maybe I don't know what data will be added to my array.

Comment: `string[] array = { "A" , "B" };` is still [using `new` under the hood](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQBMQGoA+ABATARgFgAobAZgAI8KBhCgbxIuasuwBYKBZACgEoGTFsOz4ADAG0AuhQgIEEAJ4UAvAwoAiAIIaKSTQCFdAXwDcQ5sZLGgA===)

Comment: In your example, there is no advantage, that's why they made a change, to initialize it without `new`.

Comment: @SᴇM But you don't have to initialise the array in either syntax, no? You can declare `string[] array;` or `var array = new string[]` or `string array = new string[]` without initialisation?

Comment: @Lou you can't, you need to specify the size of the array.

Comment: Also - to the close- and/or down-voter - I'm not sure what about this question is opinion based? I'm not asking which syntax is prettier, I'm interested in whether there is a measurable performance difference or other reason why omitting new would be inadvisable.

Comment: Often when a language has multiple ways to achieve the same goal, the simpler forms came later. Don't expect a *performance* difference, merely a *developer productivity* one.

Comment: This is not really an advantage/disadvantage thing, first, it was with `new`, then with newer c# versions, developers thought, why shouldn't we remove the `new` keyword from array initialization (for simplicity/less code sake), then they removed it. That's it.

Comment: I don´t see why one is better than the other. This question is pretty opinion-based.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - From a C# beginner perspective though, I don't know whether one is better than the other. I'm not proffering or soliciting an opinion on what's better stylistically, I was interested in whether there was a performance benefit to using one or the other, which I imagine is measurable. I regularly see many such questions in [python] which are not considered opinion-based, as they can be answered with a `%timeit` call.

Comment: @SᴇM - That makes sense. I wasn't sure whether this fell into the category of 1. Different syntaxes that are suitable for different situations or 2. Different syntaxes ... just because. I guess it falls into the latter category.

Comment: Well, closed for whatever reason does not mean your question is "bad". It just means: "it can´t be answered", or at least not within a single, terse answer.

Comment: But it just was answered?

Comment: Well, many answers are not really answers in the sense of "whrong/right". In your specific case answers will likely be just *opinions* or *preferences personal*, not really *facts*. Chances are, those preference suffice your needs, but they don´t neccesarily do for the entire community.

Comment: Okay. I've reworded the question to focus on performance. I believe this is more answerable.

Comment: If you want performance, consider allocating (small) arrays on the stack using [stackalloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/stackalloc).

Answer (score -2):

Because with `new` you can specify array type, i.e. you have this code

```
var array = new[] { 1, 3, 5 }
```

this will be int, but you want it to be array of `byte`, so you can do it only with new. Also you can have array declared somewhere as class field `string[] array`, an initialization of it somewhere in constructor, so you will only see `array = { "A", "B" }` which isn't clear

Comment: Yeah but as I said, int[] and new declaration of same array can be in absolutely different places of code, and you aren't covering this example - assume you define your array at the beginning of the file and your constructor is at line 10000.

Comment: You cannot definitely tell what answer this question "at all". Because the reason may vary on the situation and code present