# returning the largest and smallest numbers as an array

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm trying to return the largest and the smallest numbers in an array as an array

for example:
`int[] arr = {5, 1, 2, 4, 9, 10, 200}`

```
public static int[] largest_smallest(int[] arr)
{
    
    
    int max = array_values.Max();
    int min = array_values.Min();
    
   //return array with largest and smallest numbers
}
```

How do I modify my code so it can have an output of: `[200, 1]`?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I just modified my question.

Comment: Do you know how to declare an array??   Declare an array and add these values to it and return that array

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-array-initialization-syntaxes

Comment: Is it possible to add an element to an array after it's initialized in c#?

Comment: yes -- you just assign to the array

Comment: Why do you need that ? just `return new[] { max, min };`

Comment: That works @ralf -- trying to be clear to someone new to programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like this

```
 int [] result  = { min, max};

 return result;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code example that returns an array with the smallest and the largest number:

```cs
int[] arr = { 3, 1, 2, 4, 9, 10, 200 };

int[] largestAndSmallest(int[] arr)
{
    int[] result = new int[2];
    result[0] = arr[0];
    result[1] = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > result[1])
        {
            result[1] = arr[i];
        }
        if (arr[i] < result[0])
        {
            result[0] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", largestAndSmallest(arr)));
```

Answer (score -1):

Using System.Linq;

int[] op_array = {};

op_array[0] = array_values.Max();

op_array[1] = array_values.Min();

Comment: You can't set elements with index 0 or 1 on an array with length 0.

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the [help].