# shorthand version of ExpandoObject or a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net

I really like the anonymous type syntax.  e.g.

```
 new {a = 1, b = 2, c = 25.2}
```

It'd be neat if there was a version like this for Expando or Dictionary.  Is there a way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use a collection initializer for Dictionary<TKey, TValue> entries?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495038/can-i-use-a-collection-initializer-for-dictionarytkey-tvalue-entries)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = 
     new Dictionary<string, object> { { "a", "foo" }, { "b", 1 } };
```

Also note that you can do

```
var O = new { A = "foo", B = 12 };
```

Answer (score 4):

If you could settle for Dictionary, you could try:

```
var dict = 
    new Dictionary<string, double> { { "a", 1 }, { "b", 2 }, { "c", 25.2 } };
```

Comment: It's striking how similar our answers our - we nerds really do think alike :)